# CKEditor: Unable to getting existing instance of CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ckeditor

I've facing problem while getting existing instance.

Text Area:

```
{{ textarea  name=ec.ec_id value=ec.ecl_body placeholder=ec.ecl_en_body   class="form-control" }}
```

CKEditor:

```
function createEditor(name)
{
    CKEDITOR.replace(name, {
        //uiColor: '#379e15',
        resize_dir: 'both',
        resize_maxWidth: '800',
        toolbarGroups: [{name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup']},
            {name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi']},
            {name: 'links'}, {name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker']}]

    });
}

createEditor(email.ec_id); //Its working
```

Getting Data:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances[email.ec_id];
```

Error:
**data is undefined**

Comment: Are you sure the `email.ec_id` matches the `ec.ec_id` name attribute you give to the `textarea`?

Comment: Yes, Its a same object

Comment: @Rory I've fond that CKEditor not return instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed, I've spend lot off time on this and finally fixed it.**

CKEditor init on both name or ID attribute.

For Example 1:

```
<textarea  id="msg_body" name="msg_body"></textarea>

CKEDITOR.replace('msg_body', {}); //Working

var instance = CKEDITOR.instances['msg_body']; //return instance
```

For Example 2:

```
<textarea  id="diffrent_id" name="msg_body"></textarea>

CKEDITOR.replace('msg_body', {}); //Working and ckeditor init successfully

var instance = CKEDITOR.instances['msg_body']; //Not Working return undefined.
```

For Example 3:

```
<textarea  id="msg_body" name="diffrent_class"></textarea>

CKEDITOR.replace('msg_body', {}); //Working

var instance = CKEDITOR.instances['msg_body']; //return instance
```

**SO in emberjs if we dont specify id field then ember auto assign a ember id thats reason I was unable to get the instance .**